# convert a list of package/class names into a parent/children data structure

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, collections, tree

I have a list of class names as follow:

```
   String s1 = "com.mycompany.project.dao.hibernate.BaseDAOHibernate";
    String s2 = "com.mycompany.project.domain.Product";
    String s3 = "com.mycompany.project.domain.ProductCategory";
    String s4 = "com.mycompany.project.service.impl.ProductServiceImpl";
    String s5 = "com.mycompany.project.domain.User";
    String s6 = "com.mycompany.project.service.impl.ProductCategoryServiceImpl";
    String s7 = "com.mycompany.project.dao.hibernate.ProductCategoryDAOHibernate";
    String s8 = "com.mycompany.project.dao.hibernate.ProductDAOHibernate";

    String[] strings = { s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8};
```

I would like to convert this array into a tree structure using the following class definition:

```
public class Item  {
    private String itemName;
    private List<Item> subItems;

}
```

the method would take the array above and produce the following object.

```
item.ItemName = "com";
item.suItems = {"mycompany"};

item2.itemName = "mycompany";
item2.subItems = {"project");

item3.itemName = {"project"};
item3.subItems = {"dao", "domain", "service"}
```

... and so on.

Please advise on how to perform this operation, knowing that I might have a list of hundreds of classes as input.

Thanks

Comment: It might be better if your subItems was a `List<Item>`, then you can use recursive methods to add and search

Comment: Thanks, Edited the question, I meant to have it List<Item>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my realization on C#, for Java you may use it as pseudocode.

```
public class Item
{
    private String itemName;
    private List<Item> subItems = new List<Item>();

    public void Push(string[] namespaces, int index)
    {
        if (index >= namespaces.Length)
            return;

        foreach (Item child in subItems)
        {
            if (child.itemName == namespaces[index])
            {
                child.Push(namespaces, index + 1);
                return;
            }
        }

        Item newChild = new Item();
        newChild.itemName = namespaces[index];
        newChild.Push(namespaces, index + 1);
        subItems.Add(newChild);
    }
}

private static void Namespaces()
{
    String s1 = "com.mycompany.project.dao.hibernate.BaseDAOHibernate";
    String s2 = "com.mycompany.project.domain.Product";
    String s3 = "com.mycompany.project.domain.ProductCategory";
    String s4 = "com.mycompany.project.service.impl.ProductServiceImpl";
    String s5 = "com.mycompany.project.domain.User";
    String s6 = "com.mycompany.project.service.impl.ProductCategoryServiceImpl";
    String s7 = "com.mycompany.project.dao.hibernate.ProductCategoryDAOHibernate";
    String s8 = "com.mycompany.project.dao.hibernate.ProductDAOHibernate";

    String[] strings = { s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8 };

    Item root = new Item();
    foreach (string s in strings)
    {
        root.Push(s.Split('.'), 0);
    }
    // Do something with root variable.
}
```

I also recommend use HashMap instead of list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code/pseudocode that might help you with your recursive method:

```
public void add(Item node, String name)
{
    String prefix = the part of the name before the first '.'
    String suffix = the part of the name after the first '.'
    if (there is no suffix)
    {
        subItems.add(new Node(prefix));
    }
    else 
    {
        Item subItem = null;
        if (subItems contains an Item whose itemName is prefix)
        {
            subItem = that item
        }
        else 
        {
            subItem = new Node(prefix);
            subItems.add(subItem);
        }
        add(subItem, suffix);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a nice recursive solution. I would suggest the use of a `Map` to speed the search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split() method on each String and loop on all the resulting arrays:

```
for (String s: strings)
{
    for (String anotherS: s.split(".");
    {
        //assign to itam classes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition a `Parent/Child` structure will be some sort of a `Tree`. Consider the following...

```
public class Item  {
   private String itemName;
   private Map<String, Item> subItems;
}

Map<String, Item> rootMap;
```

Use the `split` method suggested elsewhere then loop through the elements in the package drilling down the appropriate branches of the `rootMap`.

This is an improvement over the `List` as when you have common parent packages you would have to do a search through the `List` to find the appropriate `Item` into which to add a new package.